# How to pass id in LinkedIn custom URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linkedin-api

I have a list of articles on a web page the user is allowed to click on any article to view and share LinkedIn. But my URL is not working. when I click on the share button on linked in it is sharing as

```
https://www.Mywebsite.com/magzine/article.asp
```

instead of

```
https://www.Mywebsite.com/magzine/article.asp?id=23
```

I want to post an individual article by passing each article id into the share URL.

my share URL :

```
<li>
   <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://www.Mywebsite.com/magzine/article.asp?id=@Html.ViewData.Model.id">
       <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
   </a>
</li>
```

Is it possible to pass id like above?

Comment: Do you have proper value in `@Html.ViewData.Model.id`?

Comment: What is the _rendered_ link? Does it have the id _rendered_?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk yes I have proper value in Html.ViewData.Model.id. Even if I pass hardcoded value id =23 directly also it is not working. I tested my url here https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect. It shows what I wanted here. But my share url is not working in code

Comment: could u try with .../article.asp/1 instead

Comment: @HastaTamang i tried. No luck. I thought may be there is something wrong with me website url and I tried passing this but still did not work.  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3n8WSl3Kig">